# Getting status as 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, apache, xmlhttprequest

Hi I am using the below code for ajax call

```
alert("4");
  req.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  alert("5");
  if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
    {
    xmlDoc=req.responseXML;
    alert("xml doc received"+xmlDoc);
    txt="";
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FIRSTNAME");
    y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LASTNAME");
    alert("Response achieved"+x);
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Error!!! --> req.readyState  "+req.readyState+" Error !!! ---> req.status  "+req.status);
    }
  }


req.open("POST",url,true);
alert("6");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.send(parameters);
```

I am getting as req.readyState as 4 and req.status as 0 
what could be the problem

I am hosting a file on local apache server .
Please reply .

Comment: Not the cause, but: When dealing with ajax (or anything else asynchronous), *don't* use `alert`. `alert` stops the JavaScript interpreter and can (depending on the browser you're using) interact in odd ways with asynchronous code. Use your browser's debugger, which is not only designed for this, but which offers you *dramatically* more information. Or at worst, use `console.log`. But again, the debugger is designed specifically for helping you understand how your code is running, allowing you to examine variables, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Post Request Body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725580/html5-post-request-body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual reason for this is that you're trying to make a cross-domain call and being stopped by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prohibits cross-origin ajax calls. You should be getting an error in your developer console or network tab telling you the request has been prevented.

If you control the server in question or you can contact those who do, you may be able to (get them to) enable access from your origin via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). Provided they whitelist your origin, that works with all modern browsers, although sadly in IE8 and IE9 you have to use Microsoft's special `XDomainRequest` object rather than `XMLHttpRequest` (as of IE10, Microsoft finally joined the party).

Alternately, you might see if the server you're trying to work with supports [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) (don't confuse this with JSON), although as your request is a `POST` and JSONP is inherently a `GET` operation, they may not.