# HTML5 Post Request Body

Tags: ajax, xml, web-services, xmlhttprequest

```
function sendPost(){

alert("IN SEND POST");


var username = document.myForm.username.value;
var password = document.myForm.password.value;
alert("username"+username);
alert("password"+password);

console.log("in java script");

    var url = "some url";

    alert("IN url SEND POST");

    var data = "<MESSAGE><HEADER><LOGIN>005693</LOGIN></HEADER><SESSION><LATITUDE>0.0</LATITUDE><LONGITUDE>0.0</LONGITUDE><APP>SRO</APP><ORG>MNM</ORG><TRANSACTION>PRELOGIN</TRANSACTION><KEY>PRELOGIN/ID</KEY><TYPE>PRELOGIN</TYPE></SESSION><PAYLOAD><PRELOGIN><ID>005693</ID><USERNAME>005693</USERNAME><PASSWORD>tech@2014</PASSWORD></PRELOGIN></PAYLOAD></MESSAGE>";

console.log("2")

    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    console.log("2");
    try {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
      req = false;
    }
  }
  else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
  console.log("3");
    try {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
      try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch(e) {
        req = false;
      }
    }
  }


  console.log("4");
  req.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  console.log("5");
  if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
    {
    console.log("ready state accepted");
    xmlDoc=req.responseXML;
     console.log("xmlDoc"+xmlDoc);
     alert("xmlDoc"+xmlDoc);
    txt="";
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FIRSTNAME");
    y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LASTNAME");
     console.log("Response achieved"+x);
    }


  }


req.open("POST",url,true);
console.log("6");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xml");
req.send(data);
 console.log("7");
  return true;
  }
```

I get a response in rest client perfectly as i Want as seen in image

In Google Chrome --> I get status as 0 and ready state as 1 and then 4 
In Internet Explorer --> I get status as 200 OK and ready state goes from 1 , 2, 3, 4 but a blank xml is returned

In rest client I get a perfect hit and an xml is returned

I tried asking question in different ways but some say its a cross origin problem 
If yes please lemme know the solution via code in javascript

Please guide

[image: REST CLIENT HIT IMAGE]

Comment: You have been repeatedly asked to check the JS error console and to look at the Net tab in the browser developer tools so that you can debug this issue. You don't appear to have done that yet.

Comment: If your question isn't formed in such a way that you can get a good answer, then *edit the question*; don't ask it again and again and again…

Comment: I get a error in console.log line ... but nothing happens when i comment it ... it just goes through it what is wrong ???

Comment: "a error". **WHAT** error?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Can you lemme know how can I integrate in my existing code the CORS and you can take 100 points

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I suggest rewriting your code with jQuery's help. This would compact your code, make it cross-platform, and easier to read and maintain:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendPost(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "some url",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        data: 
            "<MESSAGE><HEADER><LOGIN>005693</LOGIN></HEADER>" +
            "<SESSION><LATITUDE>0.0</LATITUDE><LONGITUDE>0.0</LONGITUDE>" +
            "<APP>SRO</APP><ORG>MNM</ORG><TRANSACTION>PRELOGIN</TRANSACTION>" + 
            "<KEY>PRELOGIN/ID</KEY><TYPE>PRELOGIN</TYPE></SESSION>" +
            "<PAYLOAD><PRELOGIN><ID>005693</ID>" +
            "<USERNAME>" + $("#username").val() + "</USERNAME>" +
            "<PASSWORD>" + $("#password").val() + "</PASSWORD>" +
            "</PRELOGIN></PAYLOAD></MESSAGE>",
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data) {
            var firstname = $(data).find("FIRSTNAME").text();
            var lastname = $(data).find("LASTNAME").text();
            alert('Hello ' + firstname + ' ' + lastname);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Secondly, a javascript that origins from your server (e.g. www.myserver.com) can't communicate with other servers (i.e. you can't request data from www.anotherserver.com). *Well you CAN, but if so you'd need to ensure the answer sent from www.anotherserver.com would be in JSONP format - and then you would just change "dataType" in the example above to "jsonp" to be able to access the result like "data.firstname" and "data.lastname"*.

Anyway, in your case I would create a local proxy on my own webserver (in the same folder where you have the above .HTML-file) that would forward the request to the other server and return the result. Thus:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "myproxy.php",
        type: "POST", ...
```

And then in myprox.php, something like this (I'm just assuming PHP here, but this could be easily ported to ASP.NET or ASP Classic):

```
<?php
    // myproxy.php forwards the posted data to some other url, and returns the result
    $clientContext = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            'content' => http_get_request_body()
        )
    )); 
    print file_get_contents("some url", false, $clientContext);
?>
```

To clarify: This would make your HTML-page talk to myproxy.php (which lives on the same server [even in the same directory]), then myproxy.php talks to the server at "some url" which returns the data to myproxy.php, which in it's turn returns the data to your script.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

The server says it is sending `text/plain` data, not XML, so the browser won't populate `req.responseXML`. The data should be in `req.responseText`.

Comment: what should i write then here to get the plain text

Comment: "The data should be in req.responseText."

Comment: I got xml data but error is after typing console.log("something") Error: 'console' is undefined

Comment: without this console line ... i cannot retrieve data

Comment: Sounds like you are using Internet Explorer and don't have the developer tools open. Console is only available when the dev tools are open.

Comment: my jscript gives error as breaking in jscript error on enabling developers tools and it hangs

Comment: I don't know why you can't get a response in Chrome. What have you changed from the code in the question? What does the console say? What does the Net tab in the developer tools say?

Comment: Nothing ... it just goes through code ... it does not give status as 200 but as 0

Comment: And what does the console say? (It *might* say nothing, but that's unlikely) And what does the Net tab in the developer tools say? (It's highly unlikely that that will say nothing).

Comment: Now i tried on another pc ... there it does not work on even IE 11 ..It just showed alert but did not went through request The warning showed 

The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Comment: What does this line imply 

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Comment: OK... Thanks Quentin ... I have gone through cross - origin and same - origin policy through wikipedia and it seems that my chrome browser is not allowing cross origin communication 


No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 

 I got this on chrome 

Please lemme know the changes in my existing code to integrate CORS

Comment: You haven't shown the code for the web service, that is where you have to add the header giving the other website permission to read it.

Comment: u mean server side ??

Comment: Yes. There wouldn't be much point in the header if it could be set up by the page that *wants* the permission.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but can you please add a semicolon (;) at the end of the line below. There is a possibility that it doesn't work because of missing semicolon.

```
console.log("2")
```

change to

```
console.log("2");
```

Comment: JavaScript ignores these statements' semicolons if they are on one line