# Post Request in Javascript and Html

Tags: html, xml, json, web

I am trying to send web request using post method
I have a request body to send which consist of xml converted to json using
json.stringify method in javascript

I should get a xml response but this is not happening so...
I have tried to hit the url using rest console . The result is ok... but not with my code

I get ready state as 1 and then directly to 4 ... with status as 0

what is the problem

Comment: Do you have a code excerpt or live demo?

Comment: Yes I have the code and have posted as the other question but no one responds to it ... what is the problem

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725580/html5-post-request-body